# Cache Memory Blocks Organization

Tags: caching

I am not able to understand how exactly the cache is organized in the following scenario.

The cache size is 256 bytes. The cache line size is 8 bytes. All variables are 4 bytes. Assume that an array A[1024] is stored in memory locations 0-4095. Suppose if we are using fully associative mapping technique, how is the array mapped to this particular cache ? Consider that the cache is initially empty and we use LRU algorithm for replacement. During each replacement, an entire line of cache is replaced.

*Initial analysis :*

There will be 32 cache blocks each with 8 bytes length. But the variables to be stored in these locations is only 4 bytes long. I am not able to take this analysis any further as to how these array elements are mapped to the 32 cache blocks.

Comment: [cs.se] would be a more apt place to ask this question.

Comment: Disagree, it's not Science. More like basic engineering.

Comment: The question doesn't have enough data - the cache would be empty (or have other stuff in it) until you actually **access** this array. Then, it depends on the order of access, which you didn't write. It would also depend on the cache replacement policy which you also didn't write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume it's accessed sequentially:

```
for (int i=0; i<1024; ++i) 
    read(A[i]);
```

In that case, you'll fill the first 64 elements (`A[0]` through `A[63]`) into the 32 cache blocks in adjacent pairs like MSalters said.

The next access would have to kick out the least recently used line, which, since you access the array in sequential order is A[64]. It would have to pick a victim to kick out, and since you're using LRU that would be the first block (way 0). You therefore replace `A[0]` and `A[1]` with `A[64]` and `A[65]` and so on, so in general you'll have element `i` mapped into way `floor(i/2)%32`.

Now computing the hit rate requires an additional assumption - each memory line fetched is the size of a full block (8 bytes), since you can't fill half blocks (actually there are ways using mask bits, but let's assume the simple case). We therefore get each second element "for free" - fetching `A[0]` would also fetch `A[1]` and so on. In theory this means that the hit rate could be 50% (miss even elements, hit odds, in reality most CPUs would perform the accesses in parallel so you won't really have that hit rate, but let's say the accesses are serialized here).

Note that each new block fetched after the first 64 elements would have to evict a block from the cache, if processing the elements also modifies them you'll have to write them back too.

Answer (score 0):

Elements `A[0]` and `A[1]` are stored in adjacent memory locations, 0-4 and 4-8. That means they share the first cache block. The other elements are similarly mapped pairwise to a cache line. Which pair goes where?

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure how the array is organized in to blocks when it is brought into the cache.